# Where to store an rsa key pair

Tags: javascript, browser, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am building a React.JS application that is supposed to encrypt and decrypt data.

I'm using the subtlecrypto api to create RSA key pairs. I want to store them, preferably in the browser, in a way the user can re-use them when he returns to the site.

I absolutely do NOT want to store them in any kind of server or online storage, because that would defeat the purpose of the whole exercise.

Is there a dedicated facility to store secrets like that? If not, what is the most secure option available?

Comment: Just use localStorage. It's kind of volatile though, so it depends on whether the user cannot lose the keys. If they cannot lose access, better offer them as download and let the user pick them from their hard drive when they open the app.

Comment: Don't storing private keys publicly (in user browser) makes it insecure? If it would be ReactNative, then there can be more secure options

Comment: If the client has to reset the browser/computer then the authentication is useless, and they've lost access to that data. That's why we store encrypted passwords on secure servers.

Comment: @Chris I thought of local storage, but that would be susceptible to XSS attacks, wouldn't it?

Comment: I guess. The most secure option I can think of is to store them externally and use an <input type="file"> to let the user load them into the web app. That way they can store them on a USB drive for instance.

Comment: The idea behind the project is to make async encrytion accessible to computer illiterates. I guess that begets some compromises security-wise.